# Custom View for my plugin in Outlook 2010 / 2007

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working to load my WPF control into outlook as a plugin. The only way it allows me to do is to add a custom task pane (which works perfectly fine), which is kind of hard at the UI. To maintain Outlook consistency, I would like to add my own view in the right-view of Outlook, so if the user clicks on some item in the navigation pane, I show my view. This would allow me to show Outlook data in my custom implementation to enhance the UX.

Can someone please let me know how to do this?

-Fahad

Answer (score 0):

Fahad,

Please google up "outlook form region". This sounds like exactly what you need - create your own form region (using outlook's developer tab) and re-register a specific mail for that.

example:

```
reg.Create(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Outlook\\FormRegions"))
```

Best of luck!

Nili